# Fix bad formatted JSON

Tags: php, json

I have JSON bad formatted JSON file, I want to fix this with PHP code.

here is my JSON:

```
x: 322.5, y: 174, colors: #000000, removable: true, draggable: true, rotatable: true, resizable: true, scale: 1, degree: 0, price: 0, boundingBox: false, textSize: 22, source: , originX: 322.5, originY: 174, currentColor: #000000, text: დედა, font: Arial
```

Fixed output:

```
"x": 322.5, "y": 174, "colors": "#000000", "removable": true, "draggable": true, "rotatable": true, "resizable": true, "scale": 1, "degree": 0, "price": 0, "boundingBox": false, "textSize": 22, "source": , "originX": 322.5, "originY": 174, "currentColor": "#000000", "text": "დედა", "font": "Arial"
```

How to correct my JSON? PHP can handle it?

Comment: If the file doesn't have quotes in the right place, how is PHP supposed to know where they go?

Comment: Is this really supposed to be JSON to begin with?

Comment: Note that your "fixed" JSON is still not valid JSON, for a couple of reasons: 1. It needs `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end. 2. The `source` property has no value at all (it's just `"source": ,`).

Comment: You're better off fixing whatever writes the file so it produces correct JSON, rather than string to figure out what was meant.

Comment: Also if your example is the whole JSON file's contents, do it manually...

Comment: A simple look on [**JSON Lint**](http://jsonlint.com/) would've shown you what the errors were in your `json`.

Comment: I know this, This is not hard to add { symbol. I wrote cut string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is very hacky, but what if you do something like this?

```
$str = 'x: 322.5, y: 174, colors: #000000, removable: true, draggable: true, rotatable: true, resizable: true, scale: 1, degree: 0, price: 0, boundingBox: false, textSize: 22, source: , originX: 322.5, originY: 174, currentColor: #000000, text: დედა, font: Arial';
$arr = explode(',',$str);
$tempArr = array();
foreach($arr as $value){
    $temp = explode(':',$value);
    foreach($temp as $k=>$v){
        $v = trim($v);
        if($v === true || $v === "true")
            $temp[$k] = true;   
        elseif($v === false || $v === "false")
            $temp[$k] = false;
        else
            $temp[$k] = '"'.$v.'"'; 
    }
    $tempArr[] = implode(':', $temp );
}
echo implode(',', $tempArr);
```

Comment: ok, everything work fine. I make some changes and everything work. very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no quick fix here. That particular example is quite easy to parse as it has no nesting, so you could write a simple parser for it using PHP's regular expressions, making certain assumptions (properties with all numeric values should be numbers, `true` and `false` should be booleans rather than strings, completely empty properties should be completely removed, and everything else is a string), but you'd be making assumptions. The point of formats like JSON is to remove the assumptions.

As Barmar astutely pointed out, it would be much better if at all possible to fix (or ask the creater to fix) the thing producing this output.